# Como deben ser las contraseñas en pgadmin,y wamp

Tags: php, pgadmin, contraseña, wampserver

Hola intento hacer un portal que tiene conexion a base de datos con pgadmin y wampserver.
Tengo el archivo config.php que es la conexion, pero me arroja error en la linea de user y password.

Mi duda es:
**¿La contraseña del archivo config.php, la del servidor del pgadmin, y la del config.inc.php del wampserver, debe ser la misma?**

[image: Ejemplo de mi pregunta]

O si no debe ser la misma que relación tiene?
Se los agradecería, estoy aprendiendo apenas

Comment: Cuando instalas _postgreSQL_ te pide que teclees una contraseña y esa es la que debes usar. Creo que el usuario debe ser `postgres`. [Tutorial de instalación de postgreSQL en WAMP](https://beecreativos.com/postgresql-en-servidor-local-con-wamp-y-xampp/)

Answer (score 0):

Vamos por partes:

1. Wamp levanta un servidor en Windows donde está un Apache, MySQL y un PHP.
2. Estás conectando con un PostgreSQL, por lo tanto, las credenciales que tienes en el PostgreSQL deben ser las mismas en tu aplicación web.
3. Las configuraciones del `config.inc.php` creo que no debes tocarlas porque están ajenas al PostgreSQL a menos que utilices alguna cosa de MySQL/MariaDB.

Saludos